# Not sure how to handle this in react - multiple promises

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, callback, promise

So the easiest way to explain this is that I am trying to search your package.json for all your packages, then use the npm registry to see if there are new updates. I have most of that done. Accept for the following for loop:

```
import request from 'request'

export const findAllUpdates = (packageInfo) => {
  for(prop in packageInfo) {
    request('https://registry.npmjs.org/' + prop, function(err, resp) {
      json = JSON.parse(resp.body);

      if (json['dist-tags'].latest !== packageInfo[prop].version) {
        // Do something, we are not the same version so we should 
        // update some counter.
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Your `packageInfo` is a object of `key=>value` which represents either a dependency or a dev dependency from the package.json and the package-lock.json or the yarn.lock

The important part is we look at, in the above function, what you have installed, we then use the registry to get that package info and compare the latest version on the registry to that of what you have installed and then we want, ideally, to update the state of the component with the total count.

how ever the issue is that we have entered callback hell, especially with a for loop, looping over every package, making a request.

I cannot create a variable and store the response in there because it cannot be accessed after the request is made. I cannot see how using events here would work because you might have 40 packages installed as either dep or dev and thats a lot of events to fire.

And finally the proper solution might be to use promises, but the whole concept of promises is yet more callbacks with the `.then(() => {})`, `.catch(() => {})` which puts me back at square one.

The goal is to call this in a component and have the state of that component be updated with the total amount of packages that have to be updated (or at least have new versions)

**Any ideas? Am I going about this all wrong?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right to be looking at promises.

The first thing is to give yourself a promise-enabled version of `request`. There's a [`promisify`](https://nodejs.org/api/util.html#util_util_promisify_original) function in `util` that takes a Node-callback-style function and returns a promise-enabled version. So:

```
import util from 'util';
// ...
const prequest = util.promisify(request);
```

(There's also an npm module, [`promisify`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/promisify), that can do entire APIs all at once.)

Then, do your requests, gathering the promises in an array (and using `then` on them to do any post-processing; `then` returns a new promise, so we're still good), and use `Promise.all` to wait until they all resolve (or any of them rejects);

So all together:

```
import request from 'request';
import util from 'util';

const prequest = util.promisify(request);

export const findAllUpdates = (packageInfo) => {
  const updates = []
  for (const prop in packageInfo) {
    updates.push(prequest('https://registry.npmjs.org/' + prop).then(resp => {
      const json = JSON.parse(resp.body);

      if (json['dist-tags'].latest !== packageInfo[prop].version) {
        // Do something, we are not the same version so we should 
        // update some counter.
      }

      // Perhaps return something here, it will be the resolution
      // for the promise for this request; otherwise, the promise
      // will resolve with `undefined`.
    }));
  }
  return Promise.all(updates);
};
```

That overall function's promise will resolve to an array of the results of each promise in the array (in order), or (again) reject if any of them rejects.

I want to be able to suggest `async`/`await`, but it doesn't currently bring much to the table for a bunch of parallel promises. (There's been the occasional talk of `await.all` to do what `Promise.all` does, but it hasn't caught on [yet?].)

Having said that, though, if we break things up a bit it is a bit nicer with `async`/`await`:

```
import request from 'request';
import util from 'util';

const prequest = util.promisify(request);

const checkOne = async (prop) => {
  const resp = await prequest('https://registry.npmjs.org/' + prop);
  const json = JSON.parse(resp.body);
  if (json['dist-tags'].latest !== packageInfo[prop].version) {
    // Do something, we are not the same version so we should 
    // update some counter.
  }

  // Perhaps return something here, it will be the resolution
  // for the promise for this request; otherwise, the promise
  // will resolve with `undefined`.
};

export const findAllUpdates = (packageInfo) => {
  const updates = []
  for (const prop in packageInfo) {
    updates.push(checkOne(prop);
  }
  return Promise.all(updates);
};
```

And of course, if all the properties in `packageInfo` are "own" properties (not inherited), `findAllUpdates` gets a lot simpler:

```
export const findAllUpdates = (packageInfo) => {
  return Promise.all(Object.keys(packageInfo).map(checkOne));
};
```

---

Side note: I've added a few missing declarations above.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using Promise. You can make several async calls, and then wait for them using Promise.all.

If you also return a Promise from your "findAllUpdates" method, then it is easy for the caller to just update its own state when the information is available.

In React that would be something like:

```
findAllUpdates(..)
  .then(result => this.setState({
    packagesNeedUpdate: result.filter(p => !p.latest).length
  }));
```

I've created a simple example below that uses promises. It fakes the requests, but otherwise should be pretty accurate.

```js
// Fake requests. Will return version '1.0.0' after one second.
const makeRequest = url => {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve(JSON.stringify({
        'dist-tags': {
          'latest': '1.0.0'
        }
      }, null, 2));
    }, 1000);
  });
}

const findAllUpdates = (packageInfo) => {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    const promises = Object.keys(packageInfo)
      .map(prop => makeRequest('https://registry.npmjs.org/' + prop).then(JSON.parse));
      
    Promise.all(promises) // Wait for all promises
      .then(jsons => {
        const results = Object.keys(packageInfo)
          .map((prop, i) => {
            const latestInNpm = jsons[i]['dist-tags'].latest;
            const current = packageInfo[prop].version
            return {
              prop,
              latest: latestInNpm === current
            }
          });
        resolve(results); // Return result to caller
      });
  });
}

function run() {
  console.log('Loading..');
  
  const packages = {
    'react': {version: '0.0.1'},
    'angular': {version: '1.0.0'},
    'ember': {version: '0.5.0'},
    'mithril': {version: '0.9.0'}
  };
  
  findAllUpdates(packages).then(result => {
    const needUpdates = result.filter(p => !p.latest).length;
    console.log('Need updates: ', needUpdates);
  });
}

run();
```